# How can I get a comma separated list of firstnames?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, ansible-template

This is my list of addresses in a YAML file :

```yaml
addresses:
  person1:
    firstname: Maria
    lastname:  Smith
  person2:
    firstname: July
    lastname:  Weber
  person3:
    firstname: John
    lastname:  Kurt
  person4:
    firstname: Simon
    lastname:  Gates
```

What i need is a comma separated string like `Maria, July, John, Simon`

I tried the following:

```yaml
firstnames: >-
  {% set lastnames_list= [] %}
  {% for name in addresses %}
      {{ name.firstname | join(",")}}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ lastnames_list }} 

firstnames: >-
  {% set lastnames_list= [] %}
  {% for name in addresses %}
      {{ name | map(attribute="firstname") | join(",") }}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ lastnames_list }} 

firstnames: '{{ addresses | map(attribute="firstname") | join(",") }}'
```

But Ansible gives the following output:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'firstname'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple [json_query filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) can be used to achieve the result.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: '{{ addresses | json_query("@.*.firstname") | join(", ") }}'
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Maria, July, John, Simon
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) filter actually applies a filter on a sequence of objects or looks up an attribute.

But here, you do have a dictionary, not a sequence of objects nor an object with attributes only.

In order to achieve what you are looking for there is two path:

1. If you stick with your actual YAML structure, you can turn your dict back in a normalized list using Ansible [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) filter:

   ```yaml
   firstnames: "{{ addresses | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | map(attribute='firstname') | join(',') }}"
   ```
2. You can switch your dictionary into a list, changing the structure of your list of addresses this way, and then your Jinja will work:

   ```yaml
   addresses:
     - firstname: Maria
       lastname:  Smith
     - firstname: July
       lastname:  Weber
     - firstname: John
       lastname:  Kurt
     - firstname: Simon
       lastname:  Gates
   ```

   Will work with

   ```yaml
   firstnames: "{{ addresses | map(attribute='firstname') | join(',') }}"
   ```

---

Here are the working examples and their corresponding recap.

1. Playbook using `dict2items`:

   ```yaml
   - hosts: local
     gather_facts: no
     vars:
       addresses:
         person1:
           firstname: Maria
           lastname:  Smith
         person2:
           firstname: July
           lastname:  Weber
         person3:
           firstname: John
           lastname:  Kurt
         person4:
           firstname: Simon
           lastname:  Gates

     tasks:
       - debug:
           msg: "{{ addresses | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | map(attribute='firstname') | join(',') }}"
   ```

   Gives the recap:

   ```
   PLAY [local]    **************************************************************************************************************

   TASK [debug]    **************************************************************************************************************
   ok: [local] => {
       "msg": "Maria,July,John,Simon"
   }

   PLAY RECAP    ****************************************************************************************************************
   local                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
   ```
2. Playbook changing the YAML address structure:

   ```yaml
   - hosts: local
     gather_facts: no
     vars:
       addresses:
         - firstname: Maria
           lastname:  Smith
         - firstname: July
           lastname:  Weber
         - firstname: John
           lastname:  Kurt
         - firstname: Simon
           lastname:  Gates

     tasks:
       - debug:
           msg: "{{ addresses | map(attribute='firstname') | join(',') }}"
   ```

   Gives the recap:

   ```
   PLAY [local]    **************************************************************************************************************

   TASK [debug]    **************************************************************************************************************
   ok: [local] => {
       "msg": "Maria,July,John,Simon"
   }

   PLAY RECAP    ****************************************************************************************************************
   local                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
   ```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your reply. I consider changing to a list but the dictionary is used in other places in the playbook....